# How do I make this last elif statement run to append the value of the character to the array if the value isn't already in the array?

Tags: python

I am programming a hangman game and need to make an algorithm where the letter is added to a list of guesses if the letter hasn't already been guessed but the last statement doesn't seem to execute at all even if i change i to i+1 or i+2 etc it just doesnt same to match the value of len(array), but it does execute the other 2 conditions when they are met.

`

```
def arrayTest():
    array = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
    character = "b"
    for i in range(len(array)):
        print(i)
        if character == array[i]:
            print("'" +character + "'" + "is already in array")
            break
        elif character != array[i] and i < len(array):
            continue
        elif character != array[i] and i == len(array):
            array.append(character)

    for element in array:
        print(element, end=" ")

    print("\n")
```

`

Comment: `i` will *never* be equal to `len(array)` - your `range()` stops one short of that value.  Also note that the `character != array[i]` part of your `elif` conditions is pointless - you *know* that's true, because the `if` itself would have handled it otherwie.

Answer (score 1):

You can use membership operator - `in`:

```
if character in array:
    # Executes when character in array
    print("Character is in array")
elif: character not in array:
    # Executes when character is not in array
    print("Character not in array")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def arrayTest():
    array = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
    character = "b"
    if character not in array:
        array.append(character)
    else:
        print("{} is already in array".format(character))

    for element in array:
        print(element, end=" ")

    print("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

The second `elif` statement is not executed as `i` will not be equal to `len(array)`. Let's take a look at what happens in your code by adding a few print statements.

```
array = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
character = "b"

print(f'len(array) is: {len(array)}')

for i in range(0, len(array)):
    print(f'i is: {i}')
    print(f'array[i] is: {array[i]}')
```

The output of this is:

```
len(array) is: 5
i is: 0
array[i] is: a
i is: 1
array[i] is: e
i is: 2
array[i] is: i
i is: 3
array[i] is: o
i is: 4
array[i] is: u
```

In the last iteration, `i` is equal to `4`, while `len(array)` is equal to 5. `array[4]` gives you the fifth element of the array `"u"`, since the index of the first element of the array is equal to `0`.

You could try to rewrite it into something like this:

```
def arrayTest(array, character):
    if character in array:
        print(f'"{character}" is already in array.')
    else:
        array.append(character)
    
    for element in array:
        print(element, end=' ')
    
    print('\n')


array = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
character = 'b'

arrayTest(array, character)
```